# Multilanguage and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a multilanguage website. I want the URL's to be like: `http://example.com/en/blog_post/2` where `blog_post` is the name of the file `blog_post.php` and `2` is value of the parameter id.

I have this .htaccess code now

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/(.*)/([^/.]+)$ /$2?lang=$1&id=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

I tried with this line, but it doesn't work:
`RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/(.*)/([^/\.]+)$ /$2?lang=$1&id=$3 [L]`

Can you help me please :)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in your context? The error you see most likely is a bit more specific :)

Comment: I tried with this URL http://localhost:1234/en/blog_post/2 and result is Internal Server Error

Comment: Are your comments (eg. `//this make url's like site.com/en/`) in your actual file? That is certainly invalid and will cause a 500 error!

Comment: No, I only comment here :)

Comment: Your initial `Options` directive should probably have a `+`. ie. `Options +FollowSymLinks`. Without the `+` you are overwriting all other settings - although that might still be OK.

Comment: I corrected the line but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is your directive "I tried with this line" part of your .htaccess file? If so, where exactly have you included this? Is this in addition to your current directives or instead of?

Comment: Yes, it is. The line is just under:
 RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L]

Comment: Ah OK, that will certainly not work since the previous rule will always take priority - you need to include your .htaccess file _exactly_ as written. Did your .htaccess file work OK before adding that line?

Comment: The .htaccess file work fine, with and without that line, but only for pages which doesnt have parameters ID. For example: contact.php, about_us.php. For pages like: blog_post.php?id=$var it doesnt work. The full content of file is: http://pastebin.com/etruN0Lv

Answer (score 1):

I did it. It works with these lines. Thanks to everyone :)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/post/([^/\.]+)$ blog_post.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. The order of the directives was the key problem here, however, there are other issues that should be addressed to handle malformed URLs. I've added another answer explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, the order of these directives is important. The more specific rules should come before the more general rules and this is a key problem with the above. However, the pattern also needs to be changed (made more specific) to prevent other malformed URLs triggering a 500 Internal Server Error and breaking your site. eg. `/en/blog_post/2/3` (an additional - erroneous - `/something`) would still trigger a 500 error in the "fixed" code above.

So, this could be written as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/([^/.]+)$ /$2?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ /$2?lang=$1&id=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]
```

The generic `(.*)` pattern has been replaced with `([^/.]+)` to only match path segments (excluding a slash). By doing this it also means that the order no longer matters and `/en/blog_post/2/3` will simply result in a 404.

I've also removed the `L` flag on the initial `RewriteRule` directives, since you need to continue anyway to append the `.php` extension.

The `RewriteRule` substitutions should also be kept as root-relative, ie. starting with a slash. (Or you should include the `RewriteBase` directive.)

I've also added another `RewriteCond` directive to make sure that `<file>.php` actually exists before appending the file extension. If you don't do this and `<file>.php` does not exist then you will get another 500 error.

You could combine the two `RewriteRule`s into one if you don't mind having an empty `id=` parameter (which presumably your script handles anyway):

```
RewriteRule ^(bg|en)/([^/.]+)(?:/([^/.]+))?$ /$2?lang=$1&id=$3
```

This handles both `/en/blog_post` and `/en/blog_post/2` requests.